# Can both primary and secondary servers be online simultaneously in Log Shipping?

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

I am new to log shipping and I want to know can both primary and secondary servers be online at the same time like in replication, or only the primary one can be online while others get the log backups but are in a passive state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am new to log shipping and I want to know can both primary and secondary servers be online at the same time like in replication,

No, not like replication where the records in the tables at the subscriber can both be read and updated. The secondary server can be in read_only/standby and restoring mode. When in read_only/standby mode the read only queries can access the database but would either block the restore operation or be disconnected when restore happens so that is not a *truly online* in the sense you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

The secondary server could be online (in a read-only state) if you are using `RESTORE` with `STANDBY`. However, all user sessions on the secondary will be closed during the restore.

So it may be useful to keep the secondary online if you have short queries, but not as a read-only version of the database that must be available continuously.

It is useful for that specific purpose, but it's not online all the time. You can't read from a database that's in a *restoring* state.

If you have the log shipping jobs pushing backups every 5 minutes, but the restore on the secondary only runs once a day, then this will serve the purpose better. It's a trade-off of how up to date you need the secondary.